# jquery progressbar not moving on login and out

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

```
( function($) {
    $.fn.link2progress = function(seconds, callback){
            this.each(function(){
                var $this = jQuery(this);
                progreso = 100;
                timeprogress = seconds*1000;
                seconds2 = 0;
                $this.animate({
                    width: progreso+'%'
                }, {
                    duration: timeprogress, 
                    complete: function(scope, i, elem){
                      if (callback) {
                        callback.call(this, i, elem );
                      };
                    }
                });
            });
    }
    $.fn.link2pause = function(){
            this.clearQueue();
            this.stop();
    }
    $.fn.link2continue = function(){
                this.clearQueue();
    }
})(jQuery)
```

I have this as the code but it does not load in bootstrap for some reason any idea why ive been trying for hours and can not find the answers anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate. "Why does this code not run" is not a good question.

Comment: i mean when I log out and login the bar does not move and i get this error

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at '/index.php?view=login&a=y' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '/js/link2progress.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Not enough information. It is better to use jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Host your link2progress.js under a https URL (and change the script URL to https)